# Stronger (?) form of Vopenka's principle

Tags: ct.category-theory, large-cardinals

A category $\mathcal{C}$ is called $\textbf{discrete}$ if the only morphisms are identity morphisms.

Consider the following weaker notion: a category $\mathcal{C}$ is called $\textbf{totally disconnected}$ if $\text{Hom}_\mathcal{C}(C,D)=\varnothing$ for all $C\neq D$.

Vopenka's principle ($\textbf{VP}$) states that a full large subcategory $\mathcal{D}$ of a locally presentable category $\mathcal{C}$ cannot be discrete. I want to consider an anaologus statement:

($\textbf{VP2}$) Full large subcategory $\mathcal{D}$ of a locally presentable category $\mathcal{C}$ cannot be totally disconnected.

Since discrete categories are totally disconnected, $\textbf{VP2}$ implies $\textbf{VP}$. Hence $\textbf{VP2}$ can't be proven in $\textbf{ZFC}$, because $\textbf{VP}$ can't. Now I would like to know:

(1) Is there a counter-example to $\textbf{VP2}$ in $\textbf{ZFC}$? As far as I know, no counter-example to $\textbf{VP}$ has been found but since $\textbf{VP2}$ is in principle a stronger statement, perhaps we can construct one here?

(2) If not, what is the relation between $\textbf{VP}$ and $\textbf{VP2}$ inside $\textbf{ZFC}$? Are they equivalent? Or does at least consistency of $\textbf{VP}$ implies that of $\textbf{VP2}$?

(I wrote $\textbf{ZFC}$ as my set theory of choice but if there are any problems in using such a weak theory, feel free to consider some other).

Thanks!

Comment: The category of fields is a disconnected full large subcategory of the category or rings, which is locally finitely presentable. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @AlexKruckman The category of fields is "not connected" but is not "disconnected" in the sense I defined above. I guess better term for my "disconnected" would be "totally disconnected". I will edit my question appropriately.

Comment: Ah, I see! I've edited to make the quantifier on $C$ and $D$ more explicit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

VP2 is equivalent to VP because every set carries a rigid binary relation. This is similar as Lemma 6.3 in my book with Adámek. In fact, VP2 is an original formulation of VP (see Jech, Set Theory).

Comment: Thank you very much!